# Add an icon to a Qtreeview item in python and without using the QstandartItemnModel

Tags: python, qt, icons, qtreeview, pyside6

I would like to add an icon for each item in my `QTreeView`. The problem is : I am not sublassing my `QTreeView` from `QStandartItemModel` but from `QAbstractItemModel` so I don't have access to the `set_icon` method.

Here is the function I've done :

```
def set_icon(self,column : int , icon :QIcon) :
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.item_data) :
            return False
        self.icon = icon
        self.item_data[column] = self.icon
        return True
```

I copied this method from the set_data method that is found in the [treeitem.py](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_editabletreemodel.html), I thought it would work the same way.
Then, when I populate my `QTreeView`, I wrote this line so it should add an icon to the second column of the line :

```
child.set_icon(1,QIcon(":/Icons/C:/Users/E40055301/Desktop/Icones/mail.svg").pixmap(QSize()))
```

I don't have any error message, but the Icon doesn't show, so I tried to write it in many ways but none is working.

Comment: you need to make sure you are using the correct ItemDataRole when displaying the icon.  Create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the icon in the `data()` method for the `DecorationRole`.

```
def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = None):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    
    if role not in (0, 1, 2):  # using the enum values instead of names
        return None

    item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
    value = item.data(index.column())

    if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
        return value

    if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
        if value == 1:
            return QIcon('path_to_icon_1.jpg')
        if value == 2:
            return QIcon('path_to_icon_1.jpg')
```

Comment: I tried something like that a few days ago but it didn't work... What am I supposed to put in the QIcon(...) ? Should I create a self.icon in my treeitem class and return it ?

Comment: You can instantiate a QIcon in two ways. From a path to an image file: `QIcon('my_icon.jpg')` or from a QPixmap: `QIcon(my_pixmap)`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qicon.html

Comment: The icon does not need to be an attribute of the treeitem.

Comment: I am really sorry, it is still unclear for me... I am populating my `QTreeView` with numbers at the very begining. Then I want to change the number 1 into a certain icon and number 2 in another (in order to separate two types of objects that I am using in my view). The `set_data` method returns a value in a certain column so I assume it can be a `QIcon`. But when I do this : `child.set_data(1,QIcon(QPixmap(":/Icons/C:/Users/E40055301/Desktop/Icones/mail.svg")))` It shows nothing. In your solution, you have to give a `my_pixmap` in argument, so do you create it in the method ?

Comment: I've edited the data() method in order to do what I think you want it to do: Show a specific icon based on the value of the item. Please note this is the data() method of the model. The view interacts with the model not with treeItems directly.

Comment: You can also store the icon in the treeItem and get it from there but to display it, the icon has to be returned by the data() method of the model.

Comment: Thank you very much @mahkitah , it works very well !! Now, do you know a way to move this icon in the row ? those 1 and 2 are in the third column, I would like to hide that column and show the `QIcon` at the beggining of the row.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it, I only added a +1 like this to do what I wanted : `value = item.data(index.column()+1)`.